# How to recovery the publicKey with "js-ethereum-cryptography" version 2.0?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, js-ethereum-cryptography

I have a problem with the `recoverPublicKey()` method in the latest version of [js-ethereum-cryptography](/questions/tagged/js-ethereum-cryptography). I can get the values of `{ r, s, recovery }`, but I cannot recover the public key because I get an `undefined` error in the browser. Thanks for your help!

```
app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
  const { sender, recipient, amount, signature } = req.body;
  const { r, s, recovery } = signature;
  const publicKey = secp.secp256k1.recoverPublicKey({ r, s, recovery }, sender);
  console.log(publicKey.toString());
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Upgrading section](https://github.com/ethereum/js-ethereum-cryptography#upgrading) of [js-ethereum-cryptography](/questions/tagged/js-ethereum-cryptography) oficial repository:

> Upgrading from 1.0 to 2.0:
>
> 1. `secp256k1` module was changed massively:
>    before, it was using [noble-secp256k1 1.7](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-secp256k1);
>    now it uses safer [noble-curves](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves). Please refer
>    to [upgrading section from curves README](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves#upgrading).
>    Main changes to keep in mind: a) `sign` now returns `Signature` instance
>    b) `recoverPublicKey` got moved onto a `Signature` instance
> 2. node.js 14 and older support was dropped. Upgrade to node.js 16 or later.

And from [Upgrading section of noble-curves](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves#upgrading):

> Upgrading from noble-secp256k1 1.7:
>
> - `recoverPublicKey(msg, sig, rec)` was changed to `sig.recoverPublicKey(msg)`

So, you should first recreate the `signature` object from the `JSON` data, and then use it to recover the public key. Note that depending on how you serialised the (`BigInt`) `r` and `s`, you may need to convert them back to `BigInt` first.

Also, even in the old version of the library, recovery is done from the `signature` and the hash of the `transaction` data, not from the sender (as in your code).

```
const { secp256k1 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1");
const { keccak256 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/keccak");
const { utf8ToBytes } = require("ethereum-cryptography/utils");

//...

app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
    const { transaction, signature } = req.body;
    const { sender, recipient, amount } = transaction;
    const { r, s, recovery } = signature;

    //const sig = new secp256k1.Signature(BigInt(r), BigInt(s), recovery);
    const sig = new secp256k1.Signature(r, s, recovery);

    const data = JSON.stringify(transaction);
    const hash = keccak256(utf8ToBytes(data));

    //const publicKey = sig.recoverPublicKey(hash).toRawBytes();
    const publicKey = sig.recoverPublicKey(hash).toHex();
    console.log('public key:', publicKey);

    //...
});
```

Finally, depending on what you need to do with the public key, you can use the `toRawBytes()` or `toHex()` methods, and even get the uncompressed version by specifying the `isCompressed = false` parameter.